# Count number of sale by order amount

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and doing a analysis on a table that contains CustomerID, OrderAmount, RegionID. I need to count number of orders in different categories according to the OrderAmount in each region. And if there is no sales in the category, returns 0.

```
Sample of data:

CustomerID | OrderAmount | RegionID
10001      |     50      |   801
10002      |     25      |   801
10003      |     200     |   802
10001      |     100     |   802
10002      |     20      |   802
...
```

```
And my expected result is:

RegionID  |  CategoryID  |  Num_of_Sales
801       |      1       |     2          -----Below 100
801       |      2       |     0          -----100-200
802       |      1       |     2          -----Below 100
802       |      2       |     1          -----100-200
...
```

My question is:
1. How to return 0 on the category that is empty?
2. Is there a better way to write the code?(Not using UNION)

```html
WITH Category1 AS(
 SELECT * FROM Sales_Table 
 WHERE NewAmount <= 100
 )
, Category2 AS(
 SELECT * FROM Sales_Table 
 WHERE NewAmount BETWEEN 101 AND 200
 )
, [...]
SELECT Region_ID, CategoryID, Num_of_Sales
FROM (
 SELECT Region_ID, COUNT(*) AS [Num_of_Sales], 1 AS CategoryID
  FROM Category1
  GROUP BY Region_ID
UNION
 SELECT Region_ID, COUNT(*) AS [Num_of_Sales], 2 AS CategoryID
  FROM Category2
  GROUP BY Region_ID
UNION
 [...]
)z
ORDER BY Region_ID, CategoryID
```

So, I use these code and get my result, but the count did not return 0 on the 100-200 Category at Region 801.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table holding RegionID and CategoryID is needed for what you are trying to achieve. Then we can use that table to do a join as shown below.

```
 With RegCatSales as
    (   
    select RegionID,C,COUNT(*) AS [Num_of_Sales]
        from 
            (
                select RegionID,OrderAmount,
                CASE
                    WHEN OrderAmount <= 100 THEN 1
                    WHEN OrderAmount BETWEEN 101 AND 200 THEN 2
                END as C
                from Sales_Table x  
            ) xx 
        group by RegionID, C
    ), 
    Regions as
    (
        select distinct RegionID from RegCatSales
    ), 
    Categories as 
    (
        select distinct C from RegCatSales
    ), 
    RegCat AS(
        select distinct RegionID, C as CategoryID from Regions,Categories
    )


    select rc.RegionID,rc.CategoryID, ISNULL([Num_of_Sales],0) NUM_Of_Sales  from  
    RegCatSales rcs
    right join RegCat rc
    on rc.RegionID= rcs.RegionID and rc.CategoryID = rcs.C
    order by rc.RegionID, rc.CategoryID
```

Comment: Thanks, @skimad, this is much better than using union. There are more categories and regions, so I use a variable table or temp table to store them and mixed them.   
```
DECLARE @CategoryTable TABLE (CategoryID INT, CategoryName VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @CategoryTable VALUES (1,'Below 100')
INSERT INTO @CategoryTable VALUES (2,'100-200')
DECLARE @RegionTable TABLE (Region_ID INT, Region_Name VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @RegionTable VALUES (801,'City1')
INSERT INTO @RegionTable VALUES (802,'City2')

WITH BaseTable AS(
 SELECT * 
 FROM @CategoryTable, @RegionTable
) 
```